# Date is not inserting in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Date is not inserting in login_date field in database. It's showing the below error when i run the sql query in phpmyadmin

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   ''user_id','login_date','login_time','logout_date','logout_time')values('12','201'
>   at line 1

Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
$date=date("d/m/y", time());
$time=date("H:i:s",time());
$q = $_POST['id'];

$sql1="insert into entries('user_id','login_date','login_time','logout_date','logout_time')values('$q','$date','$time','$date','$time')";
$res1=mysql_query($sql1);
```

Comment: Convert 'user_id','login_date' to `user_id`,`login_date` etc for the field names.

Comment: what is your data type of login_date field in database.

Comment: maybe forgot space? `insert into () values ()`

Comment: Datatype of login_date is "date"

Comment: why so many ppl mix single quotes and backticks? It is easy: single quotes for variables, backticks for column and table names!

Answer (score 2):

With  `'` MySQL thinks, it's a string, but you want to name a column. Either you simply remove those single-quotes or you use backticks.

Like this:

```
$date=date("d/m/y", time());
$time=date("H:i:s",time());
$q = $_POST['id'];

$sql1="insert into entries(`user_id`, `login_date`, `login_time`, `logout_date`, `logout_time`)values('{$q}','{$date}','{$time}','{$date}','{$time}')";
$res1=mysql_query($sql1);
```

Comment: Here you're inserting string values `$q`, `$date`,... instead of the values of PHP variables!

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using single quotes, `'`, around your column names. Column names are not strings.

You should either not use anything or, preferably, use backticks, `, like so:

```
$sql1 = <<< SQL
    INSERT INTO `entries` (
        `user_id`,
        `login_date`,
        `login_time`,
        `logout_date`,
        `logout_time`
    ) VALUES (
        '{$q}',
        '{$date}',
        '{$time}',
        '{$date}',
        '{$time}'
    )
SQL;
```

Comment: Why are you using here document echoing? It's such an old practice that is never used anymore. You should just format your strings properly.

Comment: @Mr.E I am just old-fashioned that way, young one. Multi-line strings just look odd using quotes. The heredoc syntax lends itself well to stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

As I assume your user_id column is an Integer, you should take the $q variable out of quotes. You only need to put strings in quotes for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your database doesn't like column names in single quotes, try using

```
`user_id`
```

instead of

```
'user_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line with this

```
$sql1="insert into entries(user_id,login_date,login_time,logout_date,logout_time) values('$q','$date','$time','$date','$time')";
```

Don't user single quotes for column names.

Comment: Use concatenation for the values, here you're inserting string values ($q, $date,...) instead of values corresponding to the PHP variables

Answer (score 0):

The date format of mysql is Y-m-d so if the login_date is of type date then use :-

$date=date("Y-m-d") or $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s") for type datetime

Answer (score -1):

your values are wrap with single quotes. Use backticks.

```
$res1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries (`user_id`, `login_date`, `login_time`, `logout_date`, `logout_time`) 
             VALUES (
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($q)."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."', 
               '".mysql_real_escape_string($time)."')");

$res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
```